# msSaveBlob not working in IE

Tags: javascript, angular, download, navigator

I am trying to save the file recieved from server on client machine. This is working in Chrome and Firefox but in IE it is not working.

```
const a = document.createElement('a');
document.body.appendChild(a);
const blob = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/vnd.ms-excel'}),
              url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
console.log(navigator);
if (navigator.appVersion.toString().indexOf('.NET') > 0 && window.navigator.msSaveBlob) { // For IE
    console.log('from Explorer', window.navigator);
    window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'UnitDetails' + this.apnNumber + '.xlsx');
}
else { // For Other browsers
      a.href = url;
      a.download = 'UnitDetails' + this.apnNumber + '.xlsx';
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
 }
```

Comment: Turn down the security level and try again.

Comment: I tried that too but its not working

Comment: Any kind of error in console?

Comment: No error in console

Comment: What about url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)?  Try to move it to else block. Actually, I can't reproduce that. IE11 and IE10 successfully download data.

Comment: Bringing statement  url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) inside else block will not make any difference. I tried this on IE11

Comment: 1. Try to put 'test string' instead of response. just to make sure it is not blob problem 2. Have you tried reproducing it on another machine? I heard what such issue may be a result of broken permission for IE temp folder. 3. Can you reproduce it at https://stackblitz.com/ with angular project? (put anything instead of response from server to your code) 4. Try fileSaver library

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/file-download-test

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179031/discussion-between-andreq-frenkel-and-khush).